# How to fetch all the option values(selected/unselected) in a selectbox

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to fetch all the option values(selected/unselected) in a selectbox on click of a button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var arr = new Array;

    $("#selectboxid option").each  ( function() {
       arr.push ( $(this).val() );
    });

alert ( arr.join(',' ) );
```

in the button click

```
    $("#btn1").click ( function() {
        var arr = new Array;
        $("#selectboxid option").each ( function() {
            arr.push ( $(this).val() );
        });
        alert ( arr );
    });
```

Answer (score 15):

I think is a good opportunity to use the [Traversing/map](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/map) method:

```
var valuesArray = $("#selectId option").map(function(){
  return this.value;
}).get();
```

And if you want to get two separate arrays containing the selected and unselected values you can do something like this:

```
var values = {
  selected: [],
  unselected:[]
};

$("#selectId option").each(function(){
  values[this.selected ? 'selected' : 'unselected'].push(this.value);
});
```

After that, the `values.selected` and `values.unselected` arrays will contain the right elements.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The others are inefficient and noobish.

Answer (score 3):

err ok ..

```
$('#selectbox').click(function() {
  var allvals = [];
  $(this).find('option').each(function() { allvals.push( $(this).val() ); };
});
```

or maybe you mean

```
$('#thebutton').click(function() {
  var allvals = [];
  $('#theselectbox').find('option').each(function() { allvals.push( $(this).val() ); };
});
```