# Event handler for unselection of an Item in select menu with mutiple properties enabled

Tags: jquery-mobile, select-menu

I am using a select menu which will allow multiple selections to be done. I have an event handler

```
 $("#idInventory").change(function () {
     $("#select option:selected").each(function () {
    });
});
```

which is called when an item is selected. Here I collect what ever items are chosen . But I also need to know when each selected item is deselected so that I can track what is deselected so that I can keep track if something already chosen is now deselected by user.

**UPDATE:** I am not getting this event triggered when an item is deselected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you might be looking for:

- [How to fetch all the option values(selected/unselected) in a selectbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845107/how-to-fetch-all-the-option-valuesselected-unselected-in-a-selectbox/1845169#1845169)

Kinda working demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/5hpU2/9/

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">

        <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
            <label for="select-choice-9" class="select">Choose shipping method(s):</label> 
            <select name="select-choice-9" id="select-choice-9" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false"> 
                <option>Choose options</option> 
                <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option> 
                <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option> 
                <option value="express">Express: next day</option> 
                <option value="overnight">Overnight</option> 
            </select> 
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var values = {
    selected: [],
    unselected:[]
};

$("#select-choice-9").change(function () {
    values.selected   = [];
    values.unselected = [];

    $("#select-choice-9 option").each(function(){
        values[this.selected ? 'selected' : 'unselected'].push(this.value);
    });

    alert('Selected: '+values.selected+' Unselected: '+values.unselected);
});
```

UPDATE:

```
$("#select-choice-9").change(function () {
    values.selected   = [];
    values.unselected = [];

    $("#select-choice-9 option").each(function(){
        values[this.selected ? 'selected' : 'unselected'].push(this.value);
    });

    alert('Selected: '+values.selected+' Unselected: '+values.unselected);
}).page();
```

UPDATE #2

```
$("#select-choice-9").change(function () {
    values.selected   = [];
    values.unselected = [];

    $("#select-choice-9 option").each(function(){
        values[this.selected ? 'selected' : 'unselected'].push(this.value);
    });

    alert('Selected: '+values.selected+' Unselected: '+values.unselected);
}).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Comment: Phill, This works fine if I have added the options for select menu statically, if I have added dynamicall, it is not getting correct results.

Comment: see update. I added the page() to refresh the jQM, see if this helps

Comment: Thanks for Phill, but that does not solve the problem. Is there any way I can get the selected and unselected elements.

Comment: Update #2 .checkboxradio("refresh");

Comment: What really the problem happens is even when an unselection is done, the event handler does not get called. Even a selction is considered to be a unselection. I am yet to apply the UPDATE2. Thanks Phill

Answer (score 0):

```
$("option").click(function(){
    if(this.selected)
      //do what you want to do
});
```

Comment: updated the code in the question. I tried using what you suggested. But that did not work. The event handler that I use works, but I need to find what is currently deselected.