# How to get currently unselected option value when un selecting from multi list box

Tags: jquery

Hi I am having multi select listbox like below

```
<div id="drplist" class="id_100">
  <select>
    <option value="val1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="val3">Val 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

If I select any value I can able to get selected value from list 
using

```
$('#drplist option:selected').each(function(i, selected){
}
```

But here when I unselect one value from multi select listbox , I want currently unselected 
option value using jquery. How do I get currently unselected value?

Comment: is it a multiple select?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343262/event-handler-for-unselection-of-an-item-in-select-menu-with-mutiple-properties

Comment: yes It is multiple select

Answer (score 2):

You can try make it

```
$('#link_to_id').find('option').not(':selected').each(function(k,v){
    console.log(k,v.text, v.value);
});
```

With v.text get the Text
With v.value get the Value

Answer (score 0):

first solution is

```
$('#drplist option').each(function(i, selected){

    if (!$(this).prop('selected')) {
        noselected[key] = $(this).val();
        alert($(this).val());
    } 

}
```

other solution is

```
var notSelected = $("#myList").find('option').not(':selected');
var array = notSelected.map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

try both and check who is help full for you

this is demo lisk for you http://jsfiddle.net/XqZxu/5/